# B-Spline transformation Vs Polynomial transformation in image registration

Tags: polynomials, bspline, image-registration

What is the difference between BSpline transformation based image registration and Polynomial transformation based image registration?

Answer (score 0):

PSPLINE is an expansion. It takes a variable as input and produces more than one variable as output. The difference between PSPLINE and BSPLINE is that PSPLINE produces a piecewise polynomial, whereas BSPLINE produces a B-spline.

The is a misuse of the word polynomial for transformation.
B-splines are localized piecewise polynomial functions with conveniently adjustable (non)-continuous derivatives